# In JMS asynchronous message handling as soon as onMessage() is called, message deleted from queue

Tags: java, jms, messagebroker, openmq

**Requirement:** I want messages to be persist in queue till `onMessage()` executed successfully. If any exception occur during execution of `onMessage()` and if it is not handle then message should be redelivered to listener.

I am having Glassfish v2 as a application server. I am using OpenMQConnectionFactory and JmsTemplate to send message on queue.
**Please note that I am not using MDB.**

```
<bean id="openMQConnectionFactory"
    class="com.is.br.util.OpenMqConnectionFactoryBean">
    <property name="imqAddressList" value="mq://localhost:7676" />
    <property name="imqDefaultUsername" value="admin" />
    <property name="imqDefaultPassword" value="admin" />
</bean>
```

I tried AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE as acknowledge mode but in listener when exception thrown message is not redelivered.

**MessageProducer.java**

public void sendMessage(final String responseStream) {

```
    System.out.println("Enter into IsJmsProducer.sendMessage method");

    try {
        MessageCreator creator = new MessageCreator() {
            public Message createMessage(Session session) {
                ObjectMessage message = null;
                try {
                    message = session.createObjectMessage(responseStream);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Unable create a JMSMessage");
                }
                return message;
            }
        };

        System.out.println("Sending message to destination: " + this.destination.toString());
        this.jmsTemplate.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        this.jmsTemplate.send(this.destination, creator);
        System.out.println("SendMessage to queue successfully.");           
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("SendMessage to queue Fail." + ex);
    }
    System.out.println("Exit from IsJmsProducer.sendMessage method");

}
```

**SampleJMSConsumer.java**

```
public class SampleJMSConsumer implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
   }
}
```

Then I tried with `this.jmsTemplate.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);` and in listener I called  `message.acknowledge();` and in `catch` block I called `session.recover()` still message is not redeliver.

**SampleJMSConsumer.java**

```
public class SampleJMSConsumer implements MessageListener  {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {

        ObjectMessage objectMessage = (ObjectMessage) message;
        Object object;
        try {
            object = objectMessage.getObject();
            if (object instanceof String) {
                System.out.println("Message received - " + object.toString());
                throw new JMSException("JMS exception");
            }
            message.acknowledge();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
               session.recover();
        }
    }
```

}

When I run the program in debug mode and I send message on queue in broker admin console I am able to see the number of messages but as soon as onMessage() called number of messages get reduce by one. That means message is consumed and deleted from queue. Is that message consider as "delivered"?
 Please help me to understand why message is not redeliver when exception occur?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Ashwini. I am trying to do something similar. 
I am using JMSTemplate to send message and listners are started by DefaultMessageListenerContainer. 

My Issue is I have no session object in onMessage method to recover. How do you pass your session object to your Listner in above code?

Comment: @Ashwini I know it has been lot of time since you asked this question. But did you find what you were looking for? I'm in the exact situation now. https://stackoverflow.com/q/60372579/1051215

Answer (score 1):

I think this is by design, delivered when onmessage gets called. If you want do something about the exception you might handle it using try catch.

Assume the message was put on the queue once again, you wouls likely hit the same exception when consumed anyways.

The ack mechanisms should imo be about assuring correct delivery. Maybe what you are after is a reject mechanism where you ask the prpoducerside to send a new message?

Comment: Thanks Aksel.
I went through many JMS tutorial and I found that until a JMS message has been acknowledged, it is not considered to be successfully consumed.
You may consider the scenario that onMessage() receive the message and consumer crashes. In this scenario message is not process and also not acknowledge. In this case message should be redeliver.

Answer (score 1):

Client Acknowledge is suited for you. In your onMessage() method, once processing is over, you need to call Acknowledge otherwise if there is any exception, then you don't call Acknowledge().

Session.Recovery() stops and restarts message delivery. The delivery of the message will be from the last unacknowledged message.

Comment: Thanks Shashi,
I tried the same solution, but the problem here is as soon as onMessage() is called message get deleted from queue. How can I redeliver the message if it is not present in queue?

Comment: No, message won't be removed till you call Acknowledge() in your onMessage method when using CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE session. I suggest you check again with your test.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to verify what is the default session mode for OpenMQ. It could happen that, once you opened a connection, you can't change it, so that has to be specified upon connection openin.

Answer (score 0):

session created in consumer should set session mode to AUTO_ACK / DUPS_OK_ACK.  You haven't shared your code for starting consumer. You are setting session mode in Producer but not Consumer.