# How to stop getting messages deleted without acknowledgement in Oracle AQ?

Tags: java, oracle, jms, jax-ws, oracle-aq

I have set up a single customer Oracle AQ. I observe messages from this queue in a Java web application with `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` mode. But as soon as I receive the messages in the `onMessage` method, the messages seems to be getting deleted from the Oracle Queue. My assumption is, the message should not get deleted unless I `acknowledge` them in the client. How do I stop this?

Oracle Queue schema looks like this:

```
BEGIN DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE_TABLE(
  Queue_table => '"TESTUSER"."myqueuetable"', 
  Queue_payload_type => 'TESTUSER.messageobject', 
  multiple_consumers => false
);
END;
/

BEGIN DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE(
  Queue_name => 'TESTUSER.myqueue', 
  Queue_table => 'TESTUSER.myqueuetable', 
  Queue_type => 0, Max_retries => 5, Retry_delay => 0
);
END;
/

BEGIN dbms_aqadm.start_queue (
  queue_name => 'testuser.myqueue'
);
END;
```

I observer for the messages in my Java application like this

```
 //somewhere in my app
session = queueConnection.createQueueSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
queueReceiver = ((AQjmsSession) databaseConnectionManager.getSession())
 .createReceiver(databaseConnectionManager.getQueue(), Messageobject.getORADataFactory());
queueReceiver.setMessageListener(this);


//in my listener class
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
 AdtMessage msg = (AdtMessage) message;

 try {
  Messageobject message = (Messageobject) msg.getAdtPayload();

  if (isUserConnected(message.userId)) {
   logger.debug("Message acknowledged");
   msg.acknowledge();
   //handle the message. the message should be deleted now.
  } else {
   //i don't want the message to be deleted
  }

 } catch (JMSException | IllegalArgumentException | SQLException e) {
  logger.error("An error occurred while sending an outgoing blob", e);
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't know Oracle AQ, but I agree the message should not be deleted. It might however land in some other queue - is there a concept of 'dead letter queue' in Oracle AQ ? Also, I would recommend to change your procedure to use a transactional session .createQueueSession(true,... and rollback in case of error. That should be more secure and definitely not delete your message.

Comment: rollback has some unwanted effects. The session seems to get the messages again - even though they were delivered before the session was rolled back.

Comment: There's only very little help from Oracle. I've ended up creating a normal table for now.

Comment: You are creating a single consumer queue, for which message gets deleted as soon as it is consumed successfully. To retain the message, set retention_time to a value greater than zero. Refer to https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_aqadm.htm#ARPLS109

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a single consumer queue, for which message gets deleted as soon as it is consumed successfully.

To retain the message, set retention_time to a value greater than zero when creating a queue.

```
BEGIN 
  DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE(
    Queue_name => 'TESTUSER.myqueue', 
    Queue_table => 'TESTUSER.myqueuetable', 
    Queue_type => 0, Max_retries => 5, Retry_delay => 0,
    retention_time => 300    -- retain for next 5 minutes
  );
END;
/
```

Refer to https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_aqadm.htm#ARPLS109